# If I put a variable in the private section of a class, will the variable have more protection againsted reverse engineering?

Tags: code-review, architecture, c++, debugging

```
class LockdownUnlock{
    private:
        /*snip*/
        std::string rootCertificate;  //Will this protect the data?
        /*snip*/
    public:
    /*snip*/
}LDUnlock;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to protect against. If the application is running with the permissions of a specific user this user and more privileged users (i.e. root) can debug the application or inspect the memory. Other users cannot do it. So do you want to protect the encryption key from the user who is using the encryption?

Comment: Your question is not really about AES, but about perfectly hiding (any) data (which would make AES useless in the first place). And no, this is not possible. Someone who can access the program file content can get keys that are stored there, always. The solution is not to store keys there, or to not give people access to the file.

Comment: If you binary contains the encryption keys this means that any with some expertise on debugging can find it and decrypt the code. It is not a good idea to store, in general of course, the keys on a binary.

Comment: I'm voting the question down since you've changed your original question to a completely different one, making any already existing comments and answers not matching the question anymore. Instead you should ask a new question in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `protected` section of the class is to protect the variable from code on the same application, not to protect from the outside. `Protected` means that this variable is available to instances of this class and all subclasses. Private means the variable is acessible only from instances of this class, and public is public.

You don't even need to "reverse engineer" the application to read the certificate, reading the binary on notepad would suffice.

So no matter if you put on the `private`, `protected`, `public`, or hardcode it somewhere. If someone can read the binary, can read the certificate.